# Flutter Firebase RTDB onValue triggered multiple times

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app which needs live data from the database which was created using Firebase RTDB. I used onValue to get the live data, the problem is that the onValue is triggered multiple times when a lot of data changed at once and messed up my data processing system. Been trying to look for solutions, but still haven't managed to find one. Any help will be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
await refConnection
        .child(user!.uid).orderByChild('date_created').onValue.forEach((element) {
          if (element.snapshot.value != null) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> connection = element.snapshot.value as Map<
                dynamic,
                dynamic>;
            print("Test: $connection");
            

            connection.forEach((key, value) {
              if (connection[key]['status'] == 'connected') {
                Provider.of<ContactDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .addConnected(connection[key]);
              } else if (connection[key]['status'] == 'incoming_req') {
                Provider.of<ContactDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .addIncoming(connection[key]);
              } else if (connection[key]['status'] == 'sent_req') {
                print(connection[key]);
                Provider.of<ContactDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .addSent(connection[key]);
              }
            });

            setState();
          }
    });
```

Comment: "the onValue is triggered multiple times when a lot of data changed at once" Can you clarify what that means? The `onValue` will be called at most once for a single write operation, not multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, I meant onValue is triggered multiple times when a lot of writes occurred at once, I've solved this problem by removing the foreach, which seems to be the problem. Everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to listen for live updates? If not, then try [getting the value only once](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write#read-data-once) using `get()`.

Solution: Trying with a different approach

Comment: I used .once() before, but after some considerations, I do need it to be live since the data can be changed by others as well.

Comment: I think you would need to try a different approach. the `.onValue()` will always trigger unexpectedly (production-wise) and not to mention it will iterate because of the `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide an example about your user child structure?

As I can determine by your code, do you have multiple items with different data inside your user child, each data with a field called **status**?

If that is correct, then you should use onChildChanged listener to list only when a child inside userId is changed.

That will be triggered when any child inside userId change its value, then you can verify if the childChanged.key == status then do your logic

But keep aware of the fact that any value changed inside userId child, will trigger your listener.

**avoid cyclic calls**

Comment: I recommend to read [ask] and turn this "self-dialog" into an assertive explained answer. Note that I do like the explaining part, keep it. But try to drop the questions.